# how to get the viewsource of page at dynamically in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 i want to get the view source of this page "http://localhost:3000/splash_templates/edit_template/10017".
```

I used httpclient gem, but with this am getting the view source of login page.
   So how to set the authentication and how to get the view source

Comment: Did you google it? Or at least gone through the library documentation of httpClient ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it before but you need to first authenticate user and then get content.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient this url will help you. `Configuring authentication credentials` section provide way to authorize user runtime.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful. Please copy the relevant information found in the link into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to get the source of the pages. 
Although your question is not clear as to what kind of authentication is requested to be set, however here is the hint that you can go ahead with

```
Authentication with Web server. Supports BasicAuth, DigestAuth, and Negotiate/NTLM        (requires ruby/ntlm module).
clnt = HTTPClient.new
domain = 'http://dev.ctor.org/http-access2/'
user = 'user'
password = 'user'
clnt.set_auth(domain, user, password)
p clnt.get_content('http://dev.ctor.org/http-access2/login').status
```

You can read more on this [Here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient)

Hope that helps ;)